# How to create Javascript Object using IIFE

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, iife

I have a Student object like the following,

```
function Student(){
      this.studentName = "";
}
Student.prototype.setStudentName=function(studentName){
      this.studentName = studentName;
}
Student.prototype.getStudentName=function(){
      return this.studentName;
}
```

It works when I do `new Student();`. But If I create the same Object like the following it gives an error,

```
(function(){

    function Student(){
          this.studentName = "";
    }
    Student.prototype.setStudentName=function(studentName){
          this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    Student.prototype.getStudentName=function(){
          return this.studentName;
    }
            })();
```

When I alert `new Student()`, I am getting an error `Student is not defined`.
I tried writing `return new Student()` inside IIFE but didn't work for that also. How can I create Javascript objects using IIFE?

Comment: Try to put `function Student(){this.studentName = "";}` outside the IIFE.

Comment: The function declaration for *Student* is inside the IIFE, but your call is outside. BTW, the use of an IIFE here is a bit pointless. The only consequence is hiding *Student*, which apparently you don't want hidden. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make *Student* available outside the IIFE, return it and assign it to a global variable:

```
var Student = (function(){

    function Student(){
      this.studentName = "";
    }

    /* more code */

    return Student;
})();
```