# Return value not updated inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, iife, revealing-module-pattern

In file A, I am getting a promise inside a IIFE, and updating a variable. This variable is returned(exposed for other files).

```
var ServiceResponse = (function() {
var cardPattern = null;
getCardPattern().then(function(response) {
    console.info('Successfully fetched card pattern details.');
    cardPattern = response;
    App.init();
},
function(error) {
    console.error('Failed fetching card pattern details!');
});
return {
    cardPattern : cardPattern
}
})();
```

In file B, I am trying to consume this returned variable but i am getting null and not the updated value from the promise response.

```
var validateCreditCard = function(cardNumber, expiryMonth, expiryYear, cvv) {
var creditCardPattern = ServiceResponse.cardPattern;
```

I am making sure that from file B invocation is done only after the promise is returned, but no luck. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494821/how-to-create-javascript-object-using-iife - but also async so several issues

Comment: There is code missing. What is `getCardPattern()`? If it is an asynchronous call, that might be a part of the results you are experiencing. The second code example is incomplete (no closing curly brace).

Comment: The `then` callback is async. There is no `cardPattern` until it completes.

Comment: @AlanLarimer - getCardPattern is a function, inside which there is a ajax call made. basically it is returning a promise. no the result is not null. it is valid response. second code example is just a snippet, line 2 is important.

Comment: @adeneo - Could you pls elaborate? I am making sure that only after the promise is resolved, i am trying to fetch the value.(already mentioned in the question)

Comment: @mplungjan - That actually helped...perfect!

Comment: @adeneo so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494821/how-to-create-javascript-object-using-iife is lilely more relevant dupe